# Adding appointments to a weekview php generated calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I've created a pure PHP-driven calendar with both monthly and weekly view at once.
But now I'm stuck regarding adding appontments to the week-view. Each appointment is stored in MySQL-database with a *start* and *stop* `timestamp (Y-m-d H:i)`.

I uploaded a *light* version for you to see here: http://thomaskile.me/?side=calendar

The weekdays, and time intervals for each day, is coded like this:

```
<!--weekdays-->
<?php for($week_day=(0+$day_offset); $week_day<=(6+$day_offset); $week_day++): ?>
    <td>
        <table><tbody>
        <!--time intervals-->
        <?php for($day_time=strtotime($day_time_open_str); $day_time<(strtotime($day_time_close_str)+($day_time_interval_str*60)); $day_time+=(3600/(60/$day_time_interval_str))): ?>
            <tr><td>  </td></tr>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <!--//-->
        </tbody></table>
    </td>
<?php endfor; ?>
<!--//-->
```

Couple of notes:

- `$day_offset` defines start of the week. 0 = sunday, 1 = monday.
- `$day_time_open_str` and `$day_time_close_str` is the opening and closing hours -- e.g. "09:00" and "17:00". It is used to calculate the number of hours within a day.
- `$day_time_interval_str` actually an integer -- e.g. 15 -- which represents each intervals in minutes. This is used to calculate the total number of intervals within a day.

I get the view I want, but I can't figure out how to populate the week - each day - with the appointments stored in the database.

First I tried to put my db-query right inside "weekdays-`for`-loop", and before time intervals.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start LIKE "Y-m-d%"';
```

Then; inside "time intervals-`for`-loop" I compared the intervals timestamp with the *start* and *stop* timestamp from the appontments fetched from the database - like so:

```
<?php if(($weekday_date.' '.date('H:i',$day_time)>=$get_appointments['start'])&&($weekday_date.' '.date('H:i',$day_time)<=$get_appointments['stop'])): ?>
    <span><?=$get_appointments['customer']?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This almost worked.
Here is my problems:

- Each appointment is missing 1 -- one -- interval at the start.
  E.g. appontments starting at 10:00 gets outputted from 10:15, 12:15 starts at 12:30 and so on.. But they all stops at the right time though..
- I only get 1 -- one -- appontment for each day. I figured this is because I'm not looping trough each results for each day or something like that. And I can't figure out how or where to do that..
  My query, the same, shows me that all appointments for any given day is fetched in phpMyAdmin..

This is as far as I got. If anyone could help me out, that'll be great...

Additional info:

As I see it; I'm doing a `for`-loop for each interval throughout the day - every 15 minutes in my case. For each of those intervals, I need to check the database to see if this particular interval is somewhere between the *start* and *stop* timestamps of an appointment?

Update:
Think I got it to work.
By using `PDO::fetchAll` I'm able to loop trough all the results -- appointments -- for each interval to check if this interval is somewhere between *start* and *stop* timestamp of an appointment. Multiple appointments for each day works like a charm.
But for the time range to work properly, I had to include seconds on the *start*-time, and exclude it at the *stop*-time. If not, I lost an interval at either the beginning or the end.. But it seems to be working though. Thanks for your help Tin Tran.

Now I need to figure out how to have multiple appointments, for different handlers, at the same time..

Comment: What does your query return? using `LIKE` and `Y-m-d` looks like your data is a string and not timestamp

Comment: The query returns 1 appontment, or record, per day. `Y-m-d` could be `2013-12-12`. So the end of the query would be `WHERE start LIKE "2013-12-12%"`. This return all appointment of this day, regardless of time..

Comment: try outputting `stop` and `start` from the database and see if it's in the right format like not showing seconds or something like that\

Comment: I know it's the correct format - because if I do a `while`- or `foreach`-loop I get the expected result. So therefor the query works. It's the outputting process I don't get a hang on..

Comment: so you've solved the missing 1 interval at the start problem?

Comment: instead of hitting the database multiple times, try using data_seek method to get to beginning of your resultset to loop over and over again. syntax is different depending on what you're using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Oh. The output for *start* is `2013-12-12 09:00:00` and `2013-12-12 10:00:00` for *stop*.. Was not comparing seconds. When I did that, it worked at the beginning. But if i included seconds at the end, I lost a interval at the end. Isn't that odd? Anyway; by using seconds at the *start* and not at the *stop* It worked. Thanks for that input Tin Tran.  I'm using PDO btw.